# does mvc architecture affect SEO?

Tags: java, model-view-controller, jakarta-ee, seo

I have my MVC architecture in my webapplication.Now  the flow is as follows:

```
starter.jsp -> SERVLET ->view.jsp
```

Now view.jsp expects cetrtain request parameters to be present in request object.

When view.jsp is called using above workflow everything works fine.But if view.jsp is called directly then it does not get expected attributes in request and forwards to error.jsp

Now Will search engine directly call view.jsp? or will it travel from starter.jsp to view.jsp?

Detailed example:

```
main page has a href to a article.
href ="servlet?id=xyz"

Now servlet gets the id from request.
Servlet gets details for id from DB , puts the Object obtained from DB as request attribute 
idDetails
And forwards to view.jsp
View.jsp gets request attribute idDetails
So view.jsp expects idDetails to be present as request attribute
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is MVC.. its more SEO friendly than any website I've seen

Comment: @Aniket But u dint answer my real question.Does searchengine call view.jsp directly?

Comment: does starter.jsp or view.jsp produce viewable HTML code without authorization? You might have to modify your robots.txt

Comment: @Aniket: Can u comment on original post edit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no correlation between SEO and MVC. MVC manages the **internals** of your application while SEO is some **external** tweak. If they correlate somehow then there is something wrong with your application in my opinion.

If some files are public so the search engine can see them it is likely that they will be indexed. If in doubt you can always check your pages in google for example using the `site:` prefix.

So the point is that if you can see it google can see it.

Comment: i understand.But in mvc requires certain parameters to be presnt as request attribute.As i have mentioned in my oringinal post.Can you please comment on that?

Comment: @user93796 is your website publically viewable? Such as without authorization?

Comment: In every good MVC framework you can set arbitrary routes if you are not OK with the default.

Comment: @Aniket yes its public without authorization

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Adam's reply. SEO and MVC architecture are not related at all.

If you have fear like, what happen If "CRAWLERS" will directly access your view.jsp page, then I suggest you to use Filters and Interceptors in your application.

So here your interceptor/filter will intercept the incoming request and filter it out if they are directly made by "Crawler Algorithm" OR "Suspect User".

Comment: thanks for replying.Is this normal practice to use filters/interceport in such cases?

Comment: Yes, that is the best practice to use Filter rather than interceptor. Filter works based in Servlet API. It will filter out only those request which matching with the "URL Pattern". And in case of Interceptor, it will intercept all the coming request to the container.